# What is the best way to dynamically size an input box in Angular2+?

Tags: angular

I am experimenting with different techniques to dynamically resize an input box in Angular2+.  I tried creating a directive which gave me some trouble because I still don't fully understand how directives are used and I think I incorrectly implemented it.

I found that I could get close to what I am trying to accomplish by using `[style.width.px]="myWidth"` where `myWidth` is a variable that I can calculate in my component logic.  Although this seems to be a step in the right direction i would ideally like to use an expression instead of the `myWidth` variable to resize any input that needs to grow beyond its `min-width` defined in the CSS.

So, I am asking if anyone can guide me in the right direction to basically say something like this:

```
<input type="text" [style.width.px]="expression goes here">
```

where the expression would get the current length of the input box's content and then add a few extra pixels for padding.

Any help is appreciated, and if you need more code, I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

hmm, don't know about an Angular-ish way to achieve this, but you could (of course) utilize plain javascript to handle the "change" event to count the letters in the input field, multiply it by 10 Pixel and change the variable for the length dynamically. Angular will then re-render the input field automatically.